# creating a TFIDF vectors outputs a matrix of lesser dimension

Tags: python, feature-extraction, feature-selection

Goal: Use TFIDF on a dataframe with a single textual column

I am working on the quora question similarity problem.

I have the following problems:

1. I am passing a data frame of size (198102, 1) to a tfidfvectorizer and getting back an array of size (1,1), This is a column with all text in it.

```
cq1 =pd.DataFrame(columns=['q1'])
cq1 = pd.DataFrame(X_v_trn['question1'])
print(cq1.shape,type(cq1))
tfidfq1 = TfidfVectorizer()
X_q1 = tfidfq1.fit_transform(cq1)
print(type(X_q1),X_q1.shape,X_q1.toarray())
print(tfidfq1)
```

OUTPUT

```
(198102, 1) <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'> (1, 1) [[1.]]
TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
        dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), norm='l2', preprocessor=None, smooth_idf=True,
        stop_words=None, strip_accents=None, sublinear_tf=False,
        token_pattern='(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b', tokenizer=None, use_idf=True,
        vocabulary=None)
```

The actual output I am getting is (1,1) array whereas I expect a sparse matrix having 198102 row

Answer (score 0):

There were two rows had missing values and I used fillna('0') . This did not work.
What worked was changing it to fillna('this is bad'). After this change the TFIDF vectorizer is returning proper output.